# Solr Atomic Update error : copyField dest :'title.set_str' is not an explicit field and doesn't match a dynamicField

Tags: solr

I created a new core 'mycore' in Solr version 8.5.2 using the following managed-schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema name="default-config" version="1.6">

  <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>

  <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" docValues="true" />
  <fieldType name="strings" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" multiValued="true" docValues="true" />

  <fieldType name="boolean" class="solr.BoolField" sortMissingLast="true"/>
  <fieldType name="booleans" class="solr.BoolField" sortMissingLast="true" multiValued="true"/>

  <fieldType name="pint" class="solr.IntPointField" docValues="true"/>
  <fieldType name="pfloat" class="solr.FloatPointField" docValues="true"/>
  <fieldType name="plong" class="solr.LongPointField" docValues="true"/>
  <fieldType name="pdouble" class="solr.DoublePointField" docValues="true"/>

  <fieldType name="pints" class="solr.IntPointField" docValues="true" multiValued="true"/>
  <fieldType name="pfloats" class="solr.FloatPointField" docValues="true" multiValued="true"/>
  <fieldType name="plongs" class="solr.LongPointField" docValues="true" multiValued="true"/>
  <fieldType name="pdoubles" class="solr.DoublePointField" docValues="true" multiValued="true"/>
  <fieldType name="random" class="solr.RandomSortField" indexed="true"/>

  <fieldType name="ignored" stored="false" indexed="false" multiValued="true" class="solr.StrField" />

  <fieldType name="pdate" class="solr.DatePointField" docValues="true"/>
  <fieldType name="pdates" class="solr.DatePointField" docValues="true" multiValued="true"/>
    
  <fieldType name="binary" class="solr.BinaryField"/>

  <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  
  <field name="id" type="string" multiValued="false" indexed="true" required="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="_version_" type="plong" indexed="false" stored="false"/>
  <field name="title" type="text_general" multiValued="false" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="abstract" type="text_general" multiValued="false" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
 
</schema>
```

Then I create my first document using the following command:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 'http://localhost:9293/solr/mycore/update/json/docs?commit=true' --data-binary '
{
  "id": "01",
  "title": "Hello",
  "abstract": "Hello Brave New World!"
}'
```

But when I tried an Atomic Update with the command:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 'http://localhost:9293/solr/mycore/update/json/docs?commit=true' --data-binary '
{
  "id": "01",
  "title": { "set": "Bye" }
}'
```

I got the error message:

"msg":"copyField dest :'title.set_str' is not an explicit field and doesn't match a dynamicField."

Please, what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're posting to `/update/json/docs`. This endpoint is for indexing raw JSON documents.

Send your update the default update handler by using only `/update` as your path instead.